# How does async/await work with callbacks in the async function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

```
async setMyPhotos() {
  const newPhotos = await Promise.all(newPhotoPromises);

  someOtherPromise();  // will wait for newPhotoPromises

  syncAvatar(newPhotos[0], function(res, err) {  // does this wait for newPhotoPromises too?
    if (!err) console.log("avatar sync'd");
  });

  return newPhotos;  // return just needs to wait for newPhotoPromises
}
```

I noticed `syncAvatar` seems to work, but I'm not sure if I'm just getting lucky or not. If so, how do I make sure `syncAvatar` only runs after `newPhotoPromises` are done?

To clarify, `syncAvatar` needs to happen after `newPhotoPromises` are done, however `setMyPhotos` just needs to return the results of `newPhotoPromises`, while `syncAvatar` can happen in the background.

Comment: async/await is C#?

Comment: JavaScript ES7 too!

Comment: I was confused because the tag was only javascript :P

Comment: Of course `syncAvatar` will run after all the `newPhotoPromises` resolve. That's what `await` means. However, probably this code won't do what you want, especially if you intent to wait for `syncAvatar` to finish.

Comment: @torazaburo that is good to hear. I was under the impression that `await` is a `Promise` thing, so only `Promise` knows to `await`, but you're saying callbacks work too? I updated my post with a clarification that I do not intend to wait for `syncAvatar` to finish. I only intend for `syncAvatar` only run after `newPhotoPromises` are done.

Comment: It's not that "callbacks work too". It's that execution pauses until the await is satisfied. Then, whatever comes next is executed.

Comment: `async/await` is *not* part of ES7 (ES2016). It *will* be part of this year's release, ES2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say above that "`async` is a `Promise` thing". You're right. It is. It's basically syntactic sugar around promises to make them simpler to follow in certain contexts.

In this case, the function could actually be rewritten to look like this:

```
setMyPhotos() {
  return Promise.all(newPhotoPromises)
    .then(newPhotos => {
      someOtherPromise();

      syncAvatar(newPhotos[0], function(res, err) {
        if (!err) console.log("avatar sync'd");
      });

      return newPhotos;
    });
}
```

`await` basically tells the Javascript engine to wait for the `Promise` to be resolved before executing the rest of the function. **Everything** waits for the promise to be resolved: the function essentially pauses.

An `async` function in turn *always* returns a `Promise`, like the equivalent code above.